# Existence of a specific group(Group Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinite-groups

Does there exist an infinite group G, such that for any two non trivial subgroups H and K, H is not a subset of K and K is not a subset of H?

Comment: Yes (assuming you also require the subgroups to be proper). This is the same as all proper nontrivial subgroup having prime order, and such groups are called Tarski monsters.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Do you have an example of one of these Tarski monsters?

Comment: [Tarski monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) are horribly complicated. This comment space is too small to contain their truly remarkable construction.

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a book containing the proof. You may try to find the original papers, but they're deep.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) has references - basically Olshanskii's papers.